# SELECT with multiple JOINS Including LISTAGG with it's own JOIN

Tags: oracle, group-by, left-join, listagg

I have the following 2 queries that work perfectly when run separately.

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER, eps.TITLE, per.FULL_NAME, ext.NRP_IREF_CD, ext.RESEARCH_TYPE_CD, 
   nsf.NSF_CODE, ext.NPS_THRUST_DESCRIPTION,
   CASE
        WHEN OPTION_1 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 1'
        WHEN OPTION_2 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 2'
        WHEN OPTION_3 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 3'
        WHEN OPTION_4 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 4'
        WHEN OPTION_5 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 5'
        WHEN OPTION_6 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 6'
        WHEN OPTION_7 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 7'
        WHEN OPTION_8 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 8'
        WHEN OPTION_9 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 9' 
        WHEN OPTION_0 = 'Y' THEN 'Not Applicable'
        ELSE ''
   END ONR,       
   abs.ABSTRACT_DETAILS
FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROPOSAL_EXT_T ext
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = ext.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON per
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = per.PROPOSAL_NUMBER AND
      (per.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PI' OR per.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PD')
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_ABSTRACT abs
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = abs.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN NSF_CODES nsf
    ON eps.NSF_CODE = nsf.NSF_SEQUENCE_NUMBER    
WHERE eps.OWNED_BY_UNIT = '401' AND eps.requested_start_date_initial >= DATE '2019-10-01';
```

Results

```
--------
PROPOSAL_NUMBER    TITLE    FULL_NAME    NRP_IREF_CD ... <br />
     2028          blah       ...           ....         <br />
     2029          blah2      ...           ....         <br />
     2030          blah3      ...           ....         <br />
```

**QUERY 2**

```
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER,
   LISTAGG(sk.DESCRIPTION, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sk.DESCRIPTION) AS KEYWORDS 
FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_SCIENCE_KEYWORD key 
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = key.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN SCIENCE_KEYWORD sk
    ON key.SCIENCE_KEYWORD_CODE = sk.SCIENCE_KEYWORD_CODE
GROUP BY eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER;
```

Results

```
--------
PROPOSAL_NUMBER    KEYWORDS
     2028          Keyword_A, Keyword_B, Keyword_C, Keyword_D
     2029          Keyword_Y, Keyword_Z
     2030          Keyword_W
```

So you can see that my main table that I'm dealing with is `EPS_PROPOSAL` and the PK there is `PROPOSAL_NUMBER`.
There are other tables that leverage that PK as a FK, like `EPS_PROP_SCIENCE_KEYWORD`, where you can have multiple rows of KEYWORDS that map to the same PROPOSAL_NUMBER.  The problem is that only the ID or code is stored on that table, hence the need to JOIN with the `SCIENCE_KEYWORD` table to get at the description.

Question:
How do I combine these 2 queries so that my results will look like this:

```
Results
--------
PROPOSAL_NUMBER    TITLE    FULL_NAME    NRP_IREF_CD ...  KEYWORDS
     2028          blah       ...           ....           Keyword_A, Keyword_B, Keyword_C, Keyword_D
     2029          blah2      ...           ....           Keyword_Y, Keyword_Z
     2030          blah3      ...           ....           Keyword_W
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using ?

Comment: Where option_N columns are located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to make small modification - to add OUTER APPLY with a subquery:

```sql
SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER, eps.TITLE, per.FULL_NAME, ext.NRP_IREF_CD, ext.RESEARCH_TYPE_CD, 
   nsf.NSF_CODE, ext.NPS_THRUST_DESCRIPTION,
   CASE
        WHEN OPTION_1 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 1'
        WHEN OPTION_2 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 2'
        WHEN OPTION_3 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 3'
        WHEN OPTION_4 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 4'
        WHEN OPTION_5 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 5'
        WHEN OPTION_6 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 6'
        WHEN OPTION_7 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 7'
        WHEN OPTION_8 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 8'
        WHEN OPTION_9 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 9' 
        WHEN OPTION_0 = 'Y' THEN 'Not Applicable'
        ELSE ''
   END ONR,       
   abs.ABSTRACT_DETAILS,
   k.keywords
FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROPOSAL_EXT_T ext
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = ext.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON per
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = per.PROPOSAL_NUMBER AND
      (per.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PI' OR per.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PD')
LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_ABSTRACT abs
    ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = abs.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN NSF_CODES nsf
    ON eps.NSF_CODE = nsf.NSF_SEQUENCE_NUMBER    
OUTER APPLY(
   SELECT 
      LISTAGG(sk.DESCRIPTION, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sk.DESCRIPTION) AS KEYWORDS 
   FROM EPS_PROP_SCIENCE_KEYWORD key 
   LEFT JOIN SCIENCE_KEYWORD sk
       ON key.SCIENCE_KEYWORD_CODE = sk.SCIENCE_KEYWORD_CODE
   WHERE eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = key.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
) k
WHERE eps.OWNED_BY_UNIT = '401' AND eps.requested_start_date_initial >= DATE '2019-10-01';
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using Common Table Expression :

```
WITH Q1 AS
(
  SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER, eps.TITLE, per.FULL_NAME, ext.NRP_IREF_CD, ext.RESEARCH_TYPE_CD, 
         nsf.NSF_CODE, ext.NPS_THRUST_DESCRIPTION,
         CASE
              WHEN OPTION_1 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 1'
              WHEN OPTION_2 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 2'
              WHEN OPTION_3 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 3'
              WHEN OPTION_4 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 4'
              WHEN OPTION_5 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 5'
              WHEN OPTION_6 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 6'
              WHEN OPTION_7 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 7'
              WHEN OPTION_8 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 8'
              WHEN OPTION_9 = 'Y' THEN 'Option 9' 
              WHEN OPTION_0 = 'Y' THEN 'Not Applicable'
              ELSE ''
         END ONR,       
         abs.ABSTRACT_DETAILS
    FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
    LEFT JOIN EPS_PROPOSAL_EXT_T ext
      ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = ext.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_PERSON per
      ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = per.PROPOSAL_NUMBER AND
        (per.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PI' OR per.PROP_PERSON_ROLE_ID = 'PD')
    LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_ABSTRACT abs
      ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = abs.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN NSF_CODES nsf
      ON eps.NSF_CODE = nsf.NSF_SEQUENCE_NUMBER    
   WHERE eps.OWNED_BY_UNIT = '401' AND eps.requested_start_date_initial >= DATE'2019-10-01' 
), Q2 AS
(
  SELECT eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER,
         LISTAGG(sk.DESCRIPTION, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sk.DESCRIPTION) AS KEYWORDS
    FROM EPS_PROPOSAL eps
    LEFT JOIN EPS_PROP_SCIENCE_KEYWORD key
      ON eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = key.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN SCIENCE_KEYWORD sk
      ON key.SCIENCE_KEYWORD_CODE = sk.SCIENCE_KEYWORD_CODE
   GROUP BY eps.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
)
SELECT Q1.*, Q2.KEYWORDS
  FROM Q1
  JOIN Q2
    ON Q2.PROPOSAL_NUMBER = Q1.PROPOSAL_NUMBER
```